# Django installation tutorial

Tags: django

I am new to django and trying to complete django following the tutorial. However, I cannot proceed to the next guide. As I type Poll.objects.all(). I receive several errors. Full information is provided below.

```
>>> Poll.objects.all()
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
   Poll.objects.all()
    File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 93, in __repr__
     data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
     File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 108, in __len__
    self._result_cache.extend(self._iter)
    File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 317, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
   File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 775,   in             results_iter
for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 840, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", line 41, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 366, in execute
 six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 362, in execute
 return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
DatabaseError: no such column: polls_poll.pub_date
```

Comment: shows us the `models.py`

Answer (score 0):

Since the code given in the question is not sufficient enough, I will provide you the two possible faults:

1) The pub_date column was never created

2) The pub_date column was created, but after the table was created first. So, `python manage.py syncdb` does **not** add columns to the existing tables.

So, drop the table from SQL and then do syncdb again to solve this problem. If you do not want to drop the table, use [south](http://south.aeracode.org/)